# How to script VARBINARY to copy it from one DB to another using a script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, ado.net, varbinary

I need to generate an SQL insert script to copy data from one SQL Server to another.
So with .net, I'm reading the data a given SQL Server table and write this to a new text file which can then be executed in order to insert this data on other databases.

One of the columns is a VARBINARY(MAX).
How should and can I transform the obtained byte[] into text for the script so that it can still be inserted on the other databases?

SSMS shows this data as hex string. Is this the format to use?
I can get this same format with the following

```
BitConverter.ToString(<MyByteArray>).Replace("-", "")
```

But how can this be inserted again?
I tried

```
CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), "0xMyHexString")
```

This does an insert, but the value is not the same as in the source table.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use the Bulk Copy, or SSIS, functions?

Comment: Yes, I'm including the generated scripts with an application which just runs this script. The application already exists and everything worked fine so far so I don't want to change this. It just doesn't yet work with VARBINARY columns.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turned out you can just directly insert the hex string, no need to convert anything:

```
INSERT TableName (VarBinColumnName) 
VALUES (0xMyHexString)
```

Just don't ask why I didn't test this directly...

Comment: Why you didn't test this directly ?

Comment: Best answer ever. I was totally over-complicating this. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions on SO that may help:

[What is the fastest way to get varbinary data from SQL Server into a C# Byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731353/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-get-varbinary-data-from-sql-server-into-a-c-byte-arra)

and

[How Do I Insert A Byte[] Into an SQL Server VARBINARY column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064121/how-do-i-insert-a-byte-into-an-sql-server-varbinary-column)